# Displaying Powerpoint slides on second monitor non-sequentially using VBScript

Tags: vbscript, powerpoint, nonsequential

If a Powerpoint presentation is not currently displayed - how can I display (for example) slide 7 of 10 on the secondary monitor, using vbscript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting.

There's some clues on [Hey, Scripting Guy](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/resources/qanda/sept06/hey0905.mspx). Using [TLViewer](http://www.tlviewer.org/tlviewer/) you can see the rest of the scripting dictionary in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office10\MSPPT.OLB`, and a quick looks suggests there's a lot of power there.

Hope that helps a little.